# scipy minimize not exploring all sample space during optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to optimize only two parameters `alpha` and `beta` of a function and I am using `scipy.optimize.minimize` function with `TNC` algorithm. The objective function is mean square error of observed versus predicted. Both alpha and beta can vary between 0.1 and 0.99 during optimization. I observe that scipy.minimize is exploring only limited sample space.
[image]

The error function behaved as following during optimization

[image]

Does this mean that the algorithm is stuck in local minima?

The optimization parameters are as following:

```py
anfangwerte = np.array([0.9, 0.6])  # initial values of alpha and beta
grenze = (
    (0.1, 0.99),  # bounds for alpha
    (0.1, 0.99)   # bounds for beta
     )

res = minimize(model.objective_function,  # it returns mean square error
               x0=anfangwerte,
               method='TNC',       # 'TNC',
               tol=0.002,    #
               bounds=grenze,
               options={
                   'eps': 1e-2,      # default 1e-8
                   'scale': None,
                   'stepmax': 15,
                   'disp': True,
                   'maxiter': 100,
                   'accuracy': 0.00004,
                   'gtol': 0.00002,
                   'ftol': 0.00002
               }
               )
```

Why does the algorithm explore only limited sample space? Which parameter should I change for this?

By changing the initial values and changing optimization parameters slightly, the model does explore a lot more sample space. I used 0.1 and 0.99 as initial values of both parameters and sample space was explored as following
[image]

Interestingly, the model still converged to same MSE i.e. 167.
[image]

I still see a lot of sample space being unexplored. How can we assume that the function has found global minima?

Comment: This is a local solver. Your questions however are related to global optimization.